# React this.context returns empty object {} in React Native 0.61

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context, react-state-management

I've read some documentations and answers related to this but have not found a specific answer for my case. I run my code both on React Native 0.61 (React version 16.9.0) and Snack playground.

The problem is that `console.log(this.context)` always returns empty object like this `{}`.

The code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const AppContext = React.createContext({})

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: [
      { id: 'p1', title: 'Gaming Mouse', price: 29.99 },
      { id: 'p2', title: 'Harry Potter 3', price: 9.99 },
    ],
    cart: []
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider
        value={{
          products: this.state.products
        }}
      >
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}


export default class testScreen extends React.Component {
  static contextType = AppContext

  render() {
    console.log(this.context)

    return (
      <>
        <Text>{'Sometext'}</Text>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
<AppContext.Provider
        value={{
          products: this.state.products
        }}
      >
      <testScreen/>
      </AppContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Solution is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const AppContext = React.createContext({})

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: [
      { id: 'p1', title: 'Gaming Mouse', price: 29.99 },
      { id: 'p2', title: 'Harry Potter 3', price: 9.99 },
    ],
    cart: []
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider
        value={{
          products: this.state
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class TestScreen extends React.Component {
  static contextType = AppContext

  render() {
    console.log(this.context)

    return (
      <>
        <Text>{'Sometext'}</Text>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default function AppComponent() {
 return <App><TestScreen/></App>
}
```

Comment: Would you edit this answer to explain _how_ this solves the issue? I think future readers will get a lot more learning from it if the answer is explained.